# Assigning vector of integers

Tags: c++, vector

I am new to c++. I am implementing DHCP fingerprints for each devices
EX:

```
MOTOROLA = 01 33 03 06 15 26 28 51 58 59
windows 8= 01 15 03 06 44 46 47 31 33 121 249 43
```

I am using Hash Map for this key value pairs and have code like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, vector<int> > data;
    data["Motorola"] = {01,33,03,06,15,26,28,51,58,59};
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting error like expected primary expression before { token.

Comment: Looks like you haven't enabled support for C++11 or later. Which compiler are you using? If it's a recent version of GCC or Clang, add `-std=c++11` to the compiler flags.

Comment: I've never heard of a compiler called putty, and neither has Google, sorry. Do you mean you're using the secure shell client called putty to access the machine you're compiling the code on? In that case, which compiler are you using?

Comment: @ Mike ya secure shell and GCC version 3.4.6

Comment: gcc 3.4.6 dates from about 2006.  It will not support C++11 features.

Comment: So the problem is that your compiler is about ten years old, and doesn't understand modern C++. Are you able to use a modern compiler? That would be much better than trying to write your code in an ancient, clumsy dialect. The current version is 4,9; 4.8 also has good support for C++11.

Comment: @ Mike can i update my compiler and then compile ?

Comment: @jyotihattikatti: You tell us! Try it and see. BTW I see no hash maps here. If you think `std::map` is a hash map you're in for a shock...

Answer (score 1):

Given your comment about using gcc 3.4.6 (which dates from 2006), you cannot use C++11 features.

Assuming you cannot upgrade your compiler, you need to do something like this.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > data;
    int temp[] = {01,33,03,06,15,26,28,51,58,59};
    std::vector<int> temp_as_vec(temp, temp + 10);

    data["Motorola"] = temp_as_vec;
    return 0;
}
```

The `10` is just the number of elements in `temp`.

Answer (score 0):

Please note `std::map` is not a hash map implementation, it is a binary tree implementation. If you are looking for hashmap, you should use `std::unordered_map`.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > data;
    data.emplace("Motorola", std::vector<int> {01,33,03,06,15,26,28,51,58,59} ); 

    return 0;
}
```

For gcc compiler compatible with C++98 use following code:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > data;
    int array[]={01,33,03,06,15,26,28,51,58,59} ;
    std::vector<int> temp( array, array+10);
    data["Motorola"]=temp ; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ Steephen its is giving error as HAS NO MEMBER NAMED EMPLACE AND SAME ERROR ALSO  as above mentioned

Comment: Okei, so you may not have latest compiler, can you please share the command you are using to compile

Comment: @ steephen   g++ Myfile.cpp

Comment: @jyotihattikatti  try this, g++ -std=c++11 Myfile.cpp

Comment: @ Steephen Its giving me error as unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"

Comment: So it means you don't have latest compiler that can be enabled for C++ 11 features. Can you find the version of compiler uisng following command: g++ -v

Comment: You can download and install latest version: https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/releases.html

Comment: I corrected code compatible for your compiler in my answer, if it helps accept.

Answer (score 0):

Note:

This entire post was written on the premises that you have a c++11 compliant compiler, which you don't.

---

I have not tested this on a C++11 compiler (only on C++14), but I've noticed that:

1) You've forgot to qualify the vector in the point of instantiation of the map.

2) You've not included string.

3) I also suggest you ensure that for your compiler, c++ 11 mode is enabled, as mentioned elsewhere.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string> //was excluded
int main()
{
    //was ...std::map<std::string, vector<int> > data;
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > data;
    //This should work for c++11 and c++14, as {...} instantiates
    // an initializer_list<int>, for which std::vector has a
    // conversion constructor         
    data["Motorola"] = {01,33,03,06,15,26,28,51,58,59};
    return 0;
}
```

Regards,

Werner

Comment: @ Werner after adding #include <strings error is same

Comment: @jyoti-hattikatti, did you change your compiler flags to ensure c++11, and qualify vector with std (every time)?

Comment: @ werner  Its giving me error as unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11

Comment: What compiler are your using? What OS are you working on? What IDE are you using?

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere, your compiler does not support c++11. As mentioned elsewhere, you are not using a hash map. There are ways to circumvent this problem, apart from changing your compiler. Just say...